# No mapping information to process error in Symfony Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have read many questions about this problem and I am almost 100% sure, there is an error in the configuration, but I can't find it on the second day. Can somebody please help me?

My configuration:

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
    naming_strategy: 
    doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
    auto_mapping: true
    mappings:
        Post:
            is_bundle: false
            type: attribute
            dir:'%kernel.project_dir%/src/Core/Post/Domain/Entity'
            prefix: 'Core/Post/Domain/Entity'
            alias: Post
```

My entity:

#[Entity(repositoryClass: PostRepository::class)]
class Post
{
use IdentifierTrait;

```
public const HEADER = 'header';
public const BOD = 'body';
public const AUTHOR = 'author';

#[Column(Types::STRING, length: 140)]
private string $header;

#[Column(Types::STRING)]
private string $body;

#[Column(Types::STRING)]
private string $author;
```

}

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO, please prefer code than image in your question : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as screenshot(s). On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was using forslashes instead of backslashes in doctrine.yaml in prefix property.
Hope it will help somebody.